# zsh: command not found: apt-get

Tags: terminal, osx-lion, apt-get

To solve the following error [Cucumber Rails 3.1 uninitialized constant ActionController::Dispatcher (NameError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6576991/cucumber-rails-3-1-uninitialized-constant-actioncontrollerdispatcher-nameerro), I am following this post -> http://www.ruby-on-rails-outsourcing.com/articles/2011/01/07/getting-started-with-rvm-and-rails/ .

On running this command on my terminal,

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential bison openssl libreadline6 libreadline6-dev curl git-core zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-0 libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt-dev autoconf libc6-dev
```

I get this error: `zsh: command not found: apt-get`. Few posts suggested using Macports but I am not sure how to use that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`apt-get` is a Linux package manager. On OS X you need to use something Mac specific like Macports or [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/). I recommend trying out [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/).

Comment: So, I can use brew instead of apt-get?

Comment: You will be able to install most of the above packages with `brew`.

Answer (score -1):

Install android-sdk using brew:

```
brew install --cask android-sdk
```